# Asynchronous Processing of Data

Tags: c#, .net, collections, task-parallel-library, async-await

At the minute I am trying to put together an asynchronous tcp server to receive data which I then want to process, extracting values and inserting to sql server.

The basic concept I thought would be best is once the data is received and confirmed as the entire message, the message should then be passed of to some sort of collection to await processing on a FIFO basis, which will parse the values and insert them to sql server. I suppose this is whats known as the consumer/producer pattern.

I have been doing some looking into the best collection / way of doing this and have so far seen the BlockingCollection,ConcurrentCollection and BufferBlock using async/await and i think this may be the way to go but to be honest im not sure.

The best example i have found is on Stephen Cleary's blog in particular this article,
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html

My main reservations are that I in no way want to slow down or interrupt the receiving of messages which to me would suggest using the multiple producer/consumer example which can be seen at the above link, but what i want to know is;

- Am i correct in this assumption or is there a more suitable way of doing this in my scenario.
- And if im correct in my assumption could anyone suggest the best way of implementing this taking into consideration my use case.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the minute I am trying to put together an asynchronous tcp server to receive data which I then want to process, extracting values and inserting to sql server.

There's a common pitfall with this kind of scenario. It is usually wrong to report success back to the client when the work has yet to be done. Most of the time I've seen this design, it's because of an efficiency "requirement" self-imposed by the developer, not by the client or for technical reasons. So first, take a step back and make *absolutely sure* that you do want to return a "successful completion" message to the client when the operation has not actually completed yet.

If you are sure that's what you want to do, then there's another question you must ask: is it acceptable to lose requests? That is, after you tell the client that the operation successfully completed, will the system still be stable if the operation does not actually ever complete?

The answer to that question is usually "no." At that point, the most common architectural solution is to have an *out-of-process* reliable queue (such as an Azure queue or MSMQ), with an independent backend (such as an Azure worker role or Win32 service) that processes the queue messages. This definitely complicates the architecture, but it is a *necessary* complication if the system *must* return completion messages early *and* must not lose messages.

On the other hand, if losing messages is acceptable, then you can keep them in-memory. It is only in this case that you can use one of the in-memory producer/consumer types mentioned on my blog. This is a very rare situation, but it does happen from time to time.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking in what circumstances would a request be lost or an operation not complete. Would it be if an exception was thrown for example?

Comment: Anything that can cause an unexpected server shutdown. This can range from tripping over a power cable to a reboot after installing a Microsoft Update patch. The causes for unexpected server shutdowns can be mitigated but never eliminated, so the software must be written to handle that failure scenario.

Comment: Ah right, i see so it would be if for example there were 10 x byte[] waiting to be processed and the server / application was for some reason terminated or disconnected those unprocessed messages would essentially be gone forever where as with the out of process queue you would simply continue processing any items still in the queue as these are committed to storage somewhere.

Comment: @JohnyHarkness: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would avoid using BlockingCollection and friends for this sort of work.  Doing so encourages you to architect the entire system into a single process, which is the enemy of scalability and reliability.

I second [Stephen Cleary's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21308952/83715) of using an out-of-process queue to manage the work.  I disagree that this necessarily complicates the architecture, though - in fact, I think it can make things quite a bit simpler.  Specifically, a major complication of the original requirement ("put together an asynchronous tcp server") disappears.  Asynchronous TCP servers are a pain in the butt to write and easy to screw up - why not just skip that part altogether and be free to focus all of your energy on the post-processing code?

When I built a system like this, I used a [Redis List](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) as the task queue.  Tasks were serialized to JSON, and clients would add their task to the queue with a [RPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpush) command.  Worker processes retrieve the next task from the queue [BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/blpop), do their thing, then go back to waiting for the next task.

Advantages:

- No locks.  All synchronization comes for free from Redis (or whatever task queue you choose).
- Everything in the system is single-threaded.  *Multi-threading is hard*.
- I'm free to spin up as many worker processes as I want, across as many nodes as I want.

Comment: The clients in this case are gps devices, and as a result i have no control over how they transmit their data. The only option is to point them to a tcp port and read the bytes transmitted. Is it possible to do this with a message queue and have the worker processes read the bytes transmitted from the queue?

Comment: In the case of Redis, you would need some lightweight daemon to receive the messages from the GPS devices and translate them into RPUSH commands.  I'd be interested to know if there is a message queueing system that is "protocol-free" - just taking raw TCP packets and putting them into a reliable queue for post-processing.  It seems like it should be possible (and useful!)