# SQL Server Queue Vs MSMQ (Asynchronous TCP server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, tcp, message-queue

At the moment i am putting together an asynchronous tcp server, everything seems to be coming together but im now at the stage where i need to figure out what to do with the data once received (I should mention that it will be used for receiving data primarily and will possibly never send anything to the clients).

As it is written asynchronously i don't particularly want to do any processing of the data in the server application itself (in the handler in which the data is received) to ensure that it will perform as optimally as possible, though eventually the data needs to processed and submitted to various sql tables to be of some use.

As part of a previously asked question here on SO

[Asynchronous Processing of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304210/asynchronous-processing-of-data)

Stephen Clearly had pointed out that to ensure no messages are lost due to power failure, system failure etc i should look into some kind of message queue.

In doing so i have seen various ways of doing this, one of which being using SQL server as the host to the queue.

What im wondering is using the SQL Service Broker and a Queue going to be any quicker than doing a normal insert to a table which contains only a UID, The Data (byte array no bigger than 1024 bytes) and a processed flag? And if not what is the fastest insert to use in C#

The processing of said data will probably take place in another application on the same server which will also receive the data and host the sql server if it makes any difference.

Any advice or thoughts will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford the license fee I would recommend [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/). If you can't afford it, consider [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/). Both of which will manage the message queue for you. They both support multiple queue types such as:

1. MSMQ
2. RabbitMQ
3. ActiveMQ
4. Azure

Implementing your own queuing system in SQL Server is a poor choice in the long run. Been there, got the t-shirt.